# Regex to strip tags, retain CDATA

Tags: xml, regex, cdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Hi all,

I know how everyone loves a regex question, so here is mine. I have an XML tree within which some nodes contain CDATA. How do I return just a string containing the data?

Lets see an example

```
<xml>
  <node>I'm plain text.</node>
  <node><![CDATA[I'm text in cdata... and may contain html, <strong>yikes!</strong>]]></node>
</xml>
```

Would return

```
I'm plain text. I'm text in cdata... and may contain html, yikes!
```

I've read about not parsing an irregular language with a regular one, but I'm sure this is doable. What do you reckon guys?

Thanks,
Kevin

**EDIT:** *This was a problem that needed a quick and dirty solution to deal with a few lines of XML. I was surprised at the initial flat refusal, but from further reading (in particular from links provided later on) I see that experienced programmers know it's something that should be avoided wherever possible. Live and learn. Thanks.*

Comment: see especially this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Piskvor: Why are you linking twice to the same question?

Comment: yup, got that... and two links to the same dismissal. useful, thanks.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Oops, my bad. Didn't notice that a comment is auto-created when selecting "duplicate".

Comment: @Kin: First, don't take it so personally - you are not your code, and second, I think that "don't shoot yourself in the foot" is rather useful advice ;)

Comment: When someone asks what the best way to stab himself in the face with a fork is, really the most germane answer is "Don't stab yourself in the face with a fork."  Even if one could, in principle, do a better or worse job of stabbing himself in the face with a fork depending on the technique employed.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regex, use an XML/HTML parser.

This issue has been beaten to death.

Comment: "That's right, if you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, you're succumbing to the temptations of the dark god Cthulhu's … er … code" - Jeff Atwood. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) for an example of how hard it is to solve this problem.